# How to fix '<identifier> expected' error in HackerRank

Tags: java

I'm new to Java coding, and I'm stuck with a simple ArrayList sum code. I believe that my method is correct, but I don't understand the main method. I tried to run it many times, but it keeps saying that my input, ArrayList ar, is not 'identified'. Help needed!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    /*
     * Complete the simpleArraySum function below.
     */


    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new 
FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));

        int arCount = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine().trim());

        int[] ar = new int[arCount];

        String[] arItems = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");

        for (int arItr = 0; arItr < arCount; arItr++) {
            int arItem = Integer.parseInt(arItems[arItr].trim());
            ar[arItr] = arItem;
        }

        int result = simpleArraySum(ar);

        bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(result));
        bufferedWriter.newLine();

        bufferedWriter.close();

    }
     // Below is my code
        public static int simpleArraySum(int n, ar) { 
             /** It says that 'ar' is not identified. I tried 
   'Arraylist<Integer> 
              *  ar but it still won't work
            int sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < ar.size(); i++) {
                sum += ar.get(i);
                }

            return sum;

        }



 }
```

This is what it returns: 
Compile Message:

```
Solution.java:39: error: <identifier> expected
    public static int simpleArraySum(int n, ar) {
                                              ^
1 error
```

Comment: ar is of type `int[]`. Have you tried passing that type in? Like `...simpleArraySum(int n, int[] ar)`?

Comment: You need to declare what type `ar` is, same as you have `int` for `n`.  What's happening is the compiler thinks you're intending `ar` is the type, so it's expecting that to be followed by a variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration of type of parameters for the method `simpleArraySum` is missing.

Try the following signature, it should work

```
public static int simpleArraySum(int n,int[] ar) {
```

Comment: @Stone please let me know if this answers your question

Comment: It didn't fix it, sadly. Here's what it says:                                                                                        Solution.java:39: error: <identifier> expected
    public static int simpleArraySum(int n,int[], ar) { 
                                                ^
Solution.java:39: error: <identifier> expected
    public static int simpleArraySum(int n,int[], ar) { 
                                                    ^
2 errors

Comment: ok, that was messy. Basically, it still says that an identifier is required. I copied your code in, but a lot of errors appeared. Like this one:  required: int,int[]
  found: int[] , so I added a comma. After I added the comma, only two errors are left, but they both asked for an identifier again. Is there something wrong with my code?